# Will Node.js continue executing statements after callback?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm using node.js in a lambda function to save data to a mysql database and then send a push notification.  I would like to have a callback after saving to the database and before the push notification is sent for performance.  But I want the push code to continue execution after the callback.

This is what I have:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var apn = require("apn");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: "databaseHost",
        user: "databaseUser",
        password: "databasePassword",
        database: "databaseName",
    });

    var sql = "INSERT INTO some_table SET some_id = ?";
    var inserts = [event.someId];

    connection.query(sql, inserts, function (error, results, fields) {
        connection.end();
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            var options = {
                token: {
                    key: "key.p8",
                    keyId: "keyId",
                    teamId: "teamId"
                },
                production: true
            };
            var message = "Some Message";
            var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

            var deviceTokens = event.deviceTokenArray;

            var notification = new apn.Notification();
            notification.alert = message;

            notification.topic = "com.example.example";

            apnProvider.send(notification, deviceTokens).then((response) => {
                callback(null, event.arguments.input);
            });
        }
    });
};
```

What I would like is to have the callback that is in the `apnProvider` function to occur before that function but for that function to continue to execute.  Ideally I would like to have the push message in a separate file but I guess that's a different issue which I'll tackle later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might or might not be good practice, but it's totally doable. Just call back and have the rest of the code execute.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var apn = require("apn");

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({ /* .. */ });

    var sql = "INSERT INTO some_table SET some_id = ?";
    var inserts = [event.someId];

    connection.query(sql, inserts, function (error, results, fields) {
        connection.end();
        if (error) {
            callback(error);
        } else {
            callback(null, event.arguments.input);

            // consider moving this out to a separate lambda, the
            // function is essentially done
            var options = { /*  */ };
            var message = "Some Message";
            var apnProvider = new apn.Provider(options);

            var deviceTokens = event.deviceTokenArray;

            var notification = new apn.Notification();
            notification.alert = message;

            notification.topic = "com.example.example";

            apnProvider.send(notification, deviceTokens).then((response) => {
              console.log('log response here');
            });
        }
    });
};
```

Ideally you most likely want to split up your lambdas so they aren't doing too much. Maybe have one lambda *just* querying the database, another issuing the notifications, another one persisting some data etc.

Comment: If I were to split up the lambdas into two separate functions, one to query database and another to send the push, then would I need to call the push lambda function from the client after the database function returns?  Or could I do that from within the first database query function?

Comment: You can definitely call it from the database query function. It's just a function. Probably a good idea to extract it into a separate function anyway, for testing purposes etc. You might also want to invoke the push notification logic elsewhere.